# ¿De dónde viene la acepción de pelota como “persona aduladora”?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, coloquialismos

La decimoquinta acepción de [pelota](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SPdVcPX%7CSPeziQe), según el DRAE es:

> 15. m. y f. coloq. Persona aduladora, que hace la rosca.

No sé si este coloquialismo se entiende fuera de España, pero ahí al menos es frecuente oír expresiones como:

> Fulano le está **haciendo la pelota** al profesor, para conseguir mejores notas.
>
> Fulano **es un pelota**. No para de reírle todas las bromas estúpidas al profesor.

¿Cómo se originó este coloquialismo de *hacer la pelota/ser un pelota* para referise a una “persona aduladora”?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unos blogs afirman que viene de su octava acepción:

> 8. f. coloq. prostituta.

> Lo curioso es el origen de la acción de hacer la pelota y que derivó en la expresión, ya que proviene de los ambientes de la **prostitución callejera.**
>
> Antiguamente las **prostitutas** también eran conocidas con el término ‘pelota’ (y así lo recoge aún hoy en día el Diccionario de la RAE en su 8ª acepción), No se sabe a ciencia cierta por qué se les llamaba así, aunque parece ser que era porque las prostitutas iban pasando de mano en mano de los diferentes clientes.
>
> Cuando una de estas ‘pelotas’ andaba a la búsqueda de un cliente adulaba a los viandantes que por allí pasaban, esperando que sus palabras lo convenciera y poder hacer un servicio sexual a cambio de unas monedas. También sabían que cuanto mayor fuera la lisonja que le hicieran, mayor sería el estado de satisfacción del usuario de sus servicios y mejor la retribución.
>
> De ahí que al acto de adular a alguien, con intención de conseguir algo, acabara siendo denominado como ‘hacer la pelota’ en clara referencia a lo que hacían las prostitutas (pelotas) con los clientes.

- [El sorprendente origen de ‘hacer la pelota’ como sinónimo de adular a alguien con el fin de conseguir algo](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/el-sorprendente-origen-de-hacer-la-pelota-como-sinonimo-de-adular-a-alguien-con-el-fin-de-conseguir-algo/)
- [El origen de los dichos: Hacer la pelota](https://www.yorokobu.es/hacer-la-pelota/)